# SQL Server Management Studio 2017 - Database Diagrams - Can't change Table View

Tags: database, ssms, diagram

I'm running SSMS 2017 on a fresh Windows Server 2016 Standard install.

While using the 'Database Diagrams' feature it won't let me change from the 'Standard' view to anything else.  My account is the database owner and I've tried it with an admin login, with a new database or existing, nothing seems to matter.

This is really clean install, nothing besides SQL has been added. Has anybody else run into this?

[Trying to change table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWmBc.png)

Comment: Have same problem using v17.1

Answer (score 0):

It appears that whatever the cause of the bug, it has been fixed with release 17.2 of SSMS. I have installed it on two computers formerly having the problem and it's working now.